# Moving a Bezier handle only moves the keyframe

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, keyframes

When I grab a bezier handle on a keyframe it only moves the keyframe. This is with the aligned bezier handle type enabled as well. To top it off, when I make a new keyframe ahead of the broken ones, it defaults to the auto-clamped bezier type. The images below show what happens when I grab a handle and move it. It moves the whole thing and doesn't bend the interpolation! Before this started happening when I grabbed a handle and moved it, it would rotate the keyframe on its axis and bend the interpolation line. Now it just moves the keyframe's position on the graph. I want it to be the way it was before. [image]

Comment: This is the expected behavior.  Animation curves are meant to mimic the behavior of inbetween animation developed before computing and the handle behavior models the easing-in and easing-out behavior of such animations.  Can you rewrite your question to describe what you want to do?

Comment: well before this started happening when I grabbed a handle and moved it, it would rotate the keyframe on its axis and bend the interpolation line. Now it just moves the keyframe's position on the graph. I want it to be the way it was before.

Comment: it just started working again all of a sudden. curve bend around the center again.

Comment: Just come across the same behaviour.  Did you ever figure out what caused it and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by *Proportional Editing* being switched on.  It's easy to miss if accidentally turned on but a quick fix - just turn it off in the top right hand corner of the *Graph Editor*.